# Iframe issue on IPAD2 browsers - web socket connection associated

Tags: javascript, html

My web application loads another application within an iframe. Both applications are hosted in different servers.

the web application hosted in Iframe uses web socket connection to retrieve data from server. A large amount of data is retrieved of around 5MB.

this works smoothly on desktop browsers but not on any browser on IPAD 2. The iframe app is unable to render response received from web socket. the browser crashes and becomes un responsive. i don't see an error even when i monitor the request in fiddler when app is running on IPAD 2.

Also when i replace the iframe tag with object tag then it works smoothly on IPAD2 browsers as well.

Can any one suggest/guide me about what is the issue with iframe?